# Krein-Smulian Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, banach-spaces

I am going through the book Vector Measure by Diestel and Uhl and I got stuck in the proof of Krein-Smulian theorem given on page no.51. [image]

I understood that any sequence $(x_n)$ in $W$ is inside the closed linear span of $\{x_n:n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, that is a separable subspace of $X$. But how $W$ itself can be considered to be separable using Hahn-Banach theorem? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick a sequence in the closed convex hull of $W$. Let $Y$ be the closed subspace generated by the sequence $(x_n)$ we have chosen. Then $W_0=W \cap Y$ is a weakly compact set in the Banach space $Y$. If we prove that result in the case of separable Banach spaces it would follows that $(x_n)$ has  weakly convergent subsequence in $Y$. But the subsequence also converges weakly in $X$ since any continuous linear functional becomes a continuous linear functional on $Y$ when restricted to $Y$. That finishes the proof.

Comment: How $W\subset Y$?

Comment: @Anupam I should have considered $W \cap Y$. I have edited the answer.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy Thanks